# CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Here's the full error message:

> CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/": permission denied: unknown Entry point

I have an application that I created a docker image with and had it working fine on lambda. The image is on ECR. I deleted my lambda function, created a docker container in ECS from that image and utilized Fargate.

here is my main.tf file in my ECS module on Terraform that I used to create this task.

```
    resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "python-cloud-cluster"

}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs-service" {
  name            = "python-cloud-project"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.pcp-ecs-task-definition.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  network_configuration {
    subnets         = var.service_subnets
    security_groups = var.pcp_service_sg
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
  desired_count = 1
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "pcp-ecs-task-definition" {
  family                   = "ecs-task-definition-pcp"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = "1024"
  cpu                      = "512"
  task_role_arn            = var.task_role_arn
  execution_role_arn       = var.task_role_arn
  container_definitions    = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "pcp-container",
    "image": "775362094965.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/weather-project:latest",
    "memory": 1024,
    "cpu": 512,
    "essential": true,
    "entryPoint": ["/"],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
]
EOF
}
```

I found a base template online and altered it to fit my needs. I just realized the entry point is set to ["/"] in the task definition, which was default from the template I used. What should I be setting it to? Or this error caused by a different issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[entryPoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) is **optional**, and you don't have to specify it if you don't know what it is.

In your case it is `/` which is incorrect. It should be some executable (e.g. `/bin/bash`), and it depends on your container and what the container does. But again, its optional.

You have to check documentation of your `weather-project` container, and see what exactly it does and how to use it.